# Prestashop how to exclude an element from two or more category pages?

Tags: if-statement, smarty, prestashop

I have posted this on the prestashop forum, but this seems a more active community. So I apologise for the double posting.
Original here - http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/300434-how-to-use-an-or-statement-in-category-id-x/

This should be quite simple, but I am stumped and can't understand why this isn't working.

I have a link that appears on all category pages, but I need to list a few categories where it doesn't appear.

I have tried;

```
{if $category->id != 1433 OR $category->id != 6100}
```

and

```
{if $category->id != 1433 | $category->id != 6100}
```

and

```
{if $category->id != 1433 || $category->id != 6100}
```

None of those actually work, it seems the if statement is ignored as the link appears on both those category pages.

But

```
{if $category->id != 1433}
```

Does work.

So how can I list the category IDs in the if statement to include all categories I need to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be with AND not with OR.

```
{if $category->id != 1433 && $category->id != 6100}
```

If you have more category IDs you can consider using in_array() function like:

```
{if !in_array($category->id, $banned_categories)}
```

and you can define that array in the template (worst case), asign it from the Controller directly (better case) or do a UI for setting which categories to be "banned" (best case)